# python regex pattern grabs digits in a minimal way

Tags: python, python-3.5

I try to get miles and chains integer values from a string like "at (17.08)". The false decimal form of the input data is the choice of the data administrator. First I tried the following pattern on this string "17.08":

```
"((\d+)\.(\d\d))"
```

This behaved correctly:

```
group(0) is "17.08"
group(1) is "17.08"
group(2) is "17"
group(3) is "08"
```

but now for the "at (17.08) is a" variation: I want to be able to substitute a correctly formatted location for the "decimal" notation, with this pattern:

```
".*\(?((\d+)\.(\d\d))\)?.*"
```

When queried with re.match I get the following match groups:

```
group(0) is "(17.08)", OK.
group(1) is "7.08", where is the 1 going ?
group(2) is "7", where is the 1 going ?
group(3) is "08", still OK.
```

What am I doing wrong ?  Why does "re" behave like this ?  I have an idea this must be related to the "greedy"/"non-greedy" theme, but how ?

Comment: You're using capture groups, you should use `search` if you just intend to have one output. Use non capturing groups: `(?:stuff)` will make sure you don't capture subgroups within the regex itself.

Comment: What exactly are you try to extract? The `17`, the `08`, or `17.08`? Also, on my machine, copying your pattern and example gives `7.08`, not `17.08` as group 1.

Comment: @Tomothy32: I want to extract the 17 and the 08, but having the form 17.08 as well makes a string replace possible. Also, your try is indeed giving the correct answer for the second pattern. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the `.*\(?` part at the prefix absorbed the `1` in the input, as the opening bracket is optional and `.*` is greedy. My way of solving the issue is using the following regex instead (note the space after first `*`):

`".* \(?((\d+)\.(\d\d))\)?.*"`

Assuming you always have a space before the opening bracket (if present) or the number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It did the trick, and indeed the parenthesised form is always part of a comment, so that works out all right.